# Make JavaScript/jQuery tabs return to position on mouse out

Tags: javascript, jquery

This post is about the 3 green tabs at the top of the page (link is below). I have almost got these moving tabs how I want them, but I am not able to get the tabs to return to original position on mouse out or on a click elsewhere. Instead they move back to position after a set amount of time. How difficult is it to have them move back on mouse out?

Site is here http://theveganproject.ca/wp/

Thanks!

```
var sliding = 0;
var slideTime = '';

// Set is sliding value
function setSliding(a_ISliding){
sliding = a_ISliding;
}

// Get is sliding value
function getSliding(){
return sliding;
}

// Carry out accordian styled effect
function accordion(evt) {
el = Event.element(evt);
var eldown = getNextSibling(el);

//  If element is visible do nothing
if ($('visible') == el) {
        return;
}
if ($('visible')) {

        if( getSliding() == 1 ){
                return false;
        }

        var elup = getNextSibling($('visible'));

        setSliding( 1 );

        parellelSlide( elup, eldown );
        $('visible').id = '';

}
else{
        setSliding( 1 );
        singleSlide( eldown );
}

el.id = 'visible';
}


// Setup accordian initial state
function init() {

    var bodyPanels = document.getElementsByClassName('panel_body');
    var panels = document.getElementsByClassName('panel');
    var noPanels = panels.length;
    var percentageWidth = 100 / noPanels;
    var position = 0;

    //  Loop through body panels and panels applying required styles and adding      event listeners
for (i = 0; i < bodyPanels.length; i++) {
        bodyPanels[i].hide();
        panels[i].style.width = percentageWidth + '%';
        panels[i].style.position = 'absolute';
        panels[i].style.left = position + '%';

        Event.observe(panels[i].getElementsByTagName('h3')[0], 'mouseover', accordion, false);
        Event.observe(panels[i].getElementsByTagName('h3')[0], 'mousemove', accordion, false);
        Event.observe(document.body, 'mousemove', resetIdle, false);

        position += percentageWidth;
}

    if( $('visible') ){
    //  Set panel with id of visible to be initial displayed
        var vis = $('visible').parentNode.id+'-body';
        $(vis).show();
    }
    setIdle();
}

// Next sibling method to work around firefox issues
function getNextSibling(startBrother){
var endBrother=startBrother.nextSibling;
  while(endBrother.nodeType!=1){
    endBrother = endBrother.nextSibling;
  }
  return endBrother;
}

function parellelSlide( elup, eldown ){
    new Effect.Parallel(
    [
            new Effect.SlideUp(elup),
            new Effect.SlideDown(eldown)
    ], {
            duration: 0.3,
            afterFinish: function() { setSliding( 0 );}
    });
}

function singleSlide( eldown ){

    new Effect.Parallel(
    [
            new Effect.SlideDown(eldown)
    ], {
            duration: 0.3,
            afterFinish: function() { setSliding( 0 );}
    });
}

function resetTabs(){

var resetEl = getNextSibling( $('visible') );

setSliding( 1 );

new Effect.Parallel(
[
        new Effect.SlideUp( resetEl )
], {
        duration: 0.3,
        afterFinish: function() { setSliding( 0 );}
});

$('visible').id = '';
}

function resetIdle(){
    if( $('visible') ){
            window.clearTimeout( slideTime );
            slideTime = window.setTimeout( "resetTabs()", 1000 );
    }
}

function setIdle(){
if( $('visible') ){
    slideTime = window.setTimeout( "resetTabs()", 1000 );
}
   }

    Event.observe(window, 'load', init, false);
```

Comment: place your jquery code here....

Comment: What happens if you change the `hovertimeout` variable in the settings code to 0?

Comment: what did you try to accomplish that? Some code? i hope you arent just changeing the WP-Plugin settings..!

Comment: posted the code, It is not a wp-plugin. I guess what is needed is code to have click elsewhere on the screen minimize any open tabs.